# PSEN Pin when interfacing external memory in Harvard Architecture 8051

Tags: interface, 8051

I am a computer engineering student, we have exam soon and I am completely new to this stuff . I have thoroughly searched the Internet but couldn't find any document on how to interface external memory in Harvard Architecture in 8051 microprocessor.

I know that in Harvard Architecture, program code and other data separated by two memories. Can anyone show me that how do I interface a 2732 (4Kx8 EPROM) and 4Kx8 RAM (6116) external memory in Harvard Memory in 8051 or lead me any useful document?

At least, I need to know how PSEN pin is used when interfacing external memory in Harvard Architecture. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This pdf provides diagrams on interfacing the 8051 to 2732 EPROM and also 8155 external RAM: http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~ehwang/courses/cs120b/8051.pdf

Also got this from GoogleBooks: https://books.google.com.ng/books?id=K2qH4gW-fcUC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=2732+EPROM+psen&source=bl&ots=KmXZPDtQcq&sig=Zae0KdCCTRZfmQEwX8LFlaxpPsY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWg72YiqPKAhWH8RQKHbXTB1gQ6AEIRzAI

[image: An excerpt from the book]

Good luck.